# Node.js - Convert received file contents to binary

Tags: node.js, file, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

### Update

I've confirmed that my API is receiving a buffer; not only do I now understand why this is so, but the `isBuffer` method returns `true`.

[lambda-multipart-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-multipart-parser) also gives me a property along with the file: `encoding: '7bit'`. My understanding is that '7bit' would mean ASCII, which is compatible with 'utf-8'.

I've looked at `Buffer`'s `readSomething` methods and the `toString` method, I've looked at a number of modules on NPM, I've watched a lot of YouTube, but I haven't yet found anything that will get the buffer's data as *binary*, as required by the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) to which I need to send the data.

Anyone know how to get binary out of that buffer in Node.js?

### Original Post

My client uses [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) to allow users to select files for upload. The file data logs to the console as follows.

```
File
    lastModified: 1388268203000​
    name: "ducks.jpg"
    preview: "blob:https://example.com/c06750a8-ee86-49d8-bb20-47b88a492298"
    size: 65802
    type: "image/jpeg"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
    <prototype>: FilePrototype { name: Getter, lastModified: Getter, webkitRelativePath: Getter, … }
```

The client uses [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to `POST` `multipart/form-data` data that includes the files to my API AWS Lambda function using 'nodejs12.x' runtime.

The API function uses [lambda-multipart-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-multipart-parser) to interpret the incoming data, which logs to the console as follows.

```
{
  files: [
    {
      content: <Buffer fd fd fd fd 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 fd fd 00 43 00 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 02 02 03 02 02 02 02 02 04 03 03 02 ... 62118 more bytes>,
      filename: 'ducks.jpg',
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      fieldname: 'image[0]'
    }
  ],
  messageID: '1146'
}
```

My API function uses that file content to create a new file through the Microsoft Graph API, but the file is corrupted. I can create a non-corrupt file through the same API endpoint using Node's fs.readFile() and using Postman with Body set to 'Binary'. According to the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body), the request body should contain the file content in binary, and I'm concluding that the reason the files are corrupt is because my file content is not binary.

I've spent days on this. I have read and reviewed [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API), [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), [Having AWS API Gateway return binary](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#binary-media-types) (except I really need an array of files and the messageID), and anything else I could find. But I'm apparently not getting the right combination of things in the right formats.

How can I get the file content as binary?